# Is it possible that in one form action when i click submit, 2 entries will be inserted into database with different 1 column value (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

beginner here. My target is when I click the submit. 2 entries will be inserted into database. But the thing is, when I click submit, "side" column should be different. 1 IN and 1 OUT. Please see the photo I attached for more explanation.

[image]

Views:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>auth/form_validation">

  <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Amount" name="bet" class="form-control" id="box" required>


  <!-- change id's name to betAmount -->
  <p>CURRENT WALLET: <a style="color:blue;"><?php echo $_SESSION['currentPoints']?></a></p>

  <p class="remaining">REMAINING BALANCE:

    <a class="p-1" id="betAmountResult"></a>
  </p>

  <input type="submit" name="save" id="insert" value="Insert">

  
  </div>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
 public function form_validation()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("bet","Bet", 'required|numeric');

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
            $this->load->model("main_model");
            $data = array(
                "bet" =>$this->input->post("bet")
            );
            $this->main_model->insert_data($data);
            redirect(base_url() . "auth/inserted");
    }

    else
    {
        $this->index();
    }

    }
    public function inserted()
    {
        $this->index();
        $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Your account has been registered. You can log in now");
        
    }
}
```

Model:

```
<?php 
class Main_model extends CI_Model
{

    function insert_data($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert("bettaya",$data);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also a beginner but trying to solve your problem. You have to make two arrays in your controller one is `$data` and the second one is like `$data1`.
Now in $data array

`$data = array("side" =>"in");`

and data1 array will also have all other values like data with:

`$data1 = array("side" =>"out");`

Now send two arrays to the model.

`$this->main_model->insert_data($data, $data1);`
In your model class

```
function insert_data($data,$data1)
{
    $this->db->insert("bettaya",$data);
    $this->db->insert("bettaya",$data1);
}
```

Comment: If you found this helpful please tick the answer is right.

Comment: Hello, i found an error i thought it's fully working so i unchecked it FOR NOW. Here's the database: https://prnt.sc/w7lega

Comment: These are my codes: Controller: https://prnt.sc/w7lexq  Model: https://prnt.sc/w7lf27

Comment: @Dark From your controller and model remove the $data2 array because you are not inserting the $data2 record in the table. and what I have understood from your database screenshot is your bat column value wrong and it should be the same in both columns. If I am right then you have to follow this step. `$data = array("side" =>"in","bet"=>$this->input->post("bet"); $data1 = array("side" =>"out","bet"=>$this->input->post("bet");`